# Changing reference for one object and it changes for all in the collection

Tags: c++, collections, reference

I have created class `Person` which is member of class `Account` and then there is class `Bank` which contains `vector` of `Accounts`.

I have created one `Person` who ownes 3 `Accounts` then I wanted to `changeOnwner()` of one account but accidentally all accounts get this new owner. Code is running and it is rather intuitive. **I do not understand why reference in all 3 accounts has changed.** How to fix that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class Person{
public:
    char* name;
    int age;

    Person(char* name, int age){
        this->name = name;
        this->age = age;
    }
    ~Person(){
    }

    void show(){
        cout<<name<<" "<<age<<" yo";
    }
};
class Account{
public:
    Person& owner;
    double money;
    Account(Person* owner, double money):
        owner(*owner) , // this->owner = *owner;
        money(money)  { //Uninitialized reference member
    }
     void show(){
        cout<<"\n-------------\n";
        owner.show();
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<money<<" USD\n-------------";
    }
};

class Bank{
public:
    vector<Account*>* v;
    Bank(){
        v = new vector<Account*>();
    }
    Account* openNewAccount(Person* client, double money){
        Account* r = new Account(client, money);
        v->push_back(r);
        return r;
    }
    void zmienWlasciciela(Person& o, Account* r){
        r->owner = o;
    }
    void usunRachunek(Account* r){
        delete r;
    }
    void show(){
        for(int i = 0; i < v->size(); i++)
            v->at(i)->show();
    }
    ~Bank(){
        delete v;
    }
};



int main(){
    Bank* bank = new Bank();
    Person* thomas = new Person("thomas", 34);
    Account* r1 =  bank->openNewAccount(thomas, 64363.32);
    Account* r2 =  bank->openNewAccount(thomas, 41251.54);
    Account* r3 =  bank->openNewAccount(thomas, 3232.32);
    bank->show();

    Person* margaret = new Person("Margaret", 23);
    bank->zmienWlasciciela(*margaret, r2);
    cout<<"I have changed owner of account r2"<<endl;
    bank->show();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to follow the Rule of Three/Five.

Answer (score 0):

```
r->owner = o;
```

owner is a reference. You don't seem to understand how references work. See this example:

```
int i  = 10;
int& r1 = i;
int& r2 = i;
int& r3 = i;
int j = 4;
r1 = j;
cout << i << r1 << r2 << r3; //output is 4444
```

Perhaps the owner should be a *pointer* instead.

If you come from a C# or Java background note that references in C# and Java are much more like pointers in C++. The C++ concept of a reference is arguably more like the C# `ref` function parameters, but not restricted to function parameters. Again, I do urge you to invest in a good book as C++ cannot be properly learnt by trial and error or so-called tutorials.

Comment: Unfortunately teacher wants onwer with `&` not `*` I got problem every week because of his weird demands. Is there any way to go over it?

Comment: @user2398815: You saw the example with ints, right? So, no, unless you say that a person cannot own more than one account, I don't see a way around it.

Comment: @user2398815: By the way, don't create new accounts for each new question. That's disrespectful towards the stackoverflow community.

Comment: Is there any way to re reference like:
`ref r->owner = o` is now referenfce to o

Comment: @user2398815: No, that's the point of references - once they're bound to an object (and that has to happen during initialization), you cannot re-bind them to any other object. You can point a pointer to another object though

Answer (score 0):

Really nasty to have a reference member variable: avoid `Person& owner;` Just have it as a value.

The reason being that the thing constructing the Account object may go out of scope and you'll be left with a *dangling reference*.

Your Person class also has a problem in that if it was copied to another person;

```
Person a("name", 20);
Person b = a;
```

the name data for both point to the same area of memory. Not good as a name change on one would also change the name on the other. To get around that you'll have to override the copy constructor, or do something else like this...

Also the name data used to construct Person may go out of scope too and you'll get access violations! In the way I've used your class above, I'd get problems as the constant string "name" would go out of scope after the first ';'.

Your best bet is to use std::string name as I see you're already using stl.

Putting it all together,

```
class Person{
public:
    std::string m_name;
    unsigned m_age;

    Person(char* name, unsigned age) :
        m_name(name),
        m_age(age)
    {
    }
    ~Person()
    {
    }

    void show(){
        cout<<m_name.c_str()<<" "<<age<<" yo";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> A reference is an alias or an alternative name for an object. All
>   operations applied to a reference act on the object to which the
>   reference refers. The address of a reference is the address of the
>   aliased object.

[See here.](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr116.htm)

```
Account* r1 =  bank->openNewAccount(thomas, 64363.32);
Account* r2 =  bank->openNewAccount(thomas, 41251.54);
Account* r3 =  bank->openNewAccount(thomas, 3232.32);
```

you create three accounts for same owner, and owner of an account is a reference member of `Account`. When you changed owner for one account, you change value for reference `owner`, which is an alias for `Person` thomas. So, value is changed also for the other accounts.

As Armen illustrated,

```
int i = 10;
int& r1 = i;
int& r2 = i;
r1 = 4;
cout << i << r1 << r2; // gives 444
```

Also note here that reference has to be initialized (except for function parameters!), and cannot be reassigned : its an alias for its initialization value. So reassignment means nothing but change the value for the initializer.